# AirPods (gen 2) and AirPods Pro (gen 2) won't stop connecting to my new MacBook following iPhone call

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, airpods

I've had AirPods (gen 2) and AirPods Pro (gen 2) for several months now without any issues. However, I bought a new 2021 MacBook Pro a couple of weeks ago, replacing my previous 2021 MacBook Pro. I migrated to the new one with Migration Assistant, and it's running macOS Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82). Since then, my AirPods have been switching from my iPhone to my MacBook every time immediately after I end a call with AirPods on my iPhone. This happens even if I'm not using my Mac, e.g. if it's in another room with the screen sleeping, as long as the lid is not shut.

In macOS System Settings > Bluetooth > my AirPods > Connect to this Mac is set to "When last connected to this Mac". I have the "when last connected" option selected on all my other devices too.

- Restarting my MacBook.
- Removing my AirPods from my devices and readding them.
- Doing a hard reset on my AirPods by holding down the setup button for 15 seconds until the white light flashes amber.
- Renaming my AirPods.
- Toggling the "Connect to this Mac" setting to "Automatically" then back to "When last connected to this Mac".

At this point I'm running out of ideas short of wiping my whole Mac, which is not appealing.